# How to get transparent statusline in terminal Vim?

Tags: vim, statusline

I am using **Vim** in the default terminal of Ubuntu. I want to make the **statusline** background color be transparent, that is become the color of the Ubuntu terminal background.

I tried adding this to my vimrc:

```
hi statusline ctermfg=NONE
```

Also tried:

```
hi statusline ctermbg=NONE
```

Neither has any effect. However, if I try any named color like `red`, it works.

Is there any way to make the statusline background be transparent in terminal Vim?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, what might help is using

```
hi StatusLine ctermbg=0 cterm=NONE
```

This depends of course on your general background. 
What also works is to set a highlight-format:

```
hi StatusLine ctermbg=none cterm=bold
```

More light was shed into this problem in this post: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2381/hi-statusline-cterm-none-displays-whitespace-characters

Answer (score 0):

This command

```
:hi StatusLine ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE
```

works here.

Comment: Background color works, but now my statusline is full of ^^^^^^^^^^ characters.

Comment: what is he value of `$TERM`?

Comment: Try with `xterm-256color`.

Comment: Sorry, but still the same ^^^^^^ characters.